# Regex sub phone number format multiple times on same string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use reg expressions to modify the format of phone numbers in a list.
Here is a sample list:

```
["(123)456-7890 (321)-654-0987",
"(111) 111-1111",
"222-222-2222",
"(333)333.3333",
"(444).444.4444",
"blah blah blah (555) 555.5555",
"666.666.6666 random text"]
```

Every valid number has either a space OR start of string character leading, AND either a space OR end of string character trailing. This means that there can be random text in the strings, or multiple numbers on one line. My question is: **How can I modify the format of ALL the phone numbers with my match pattern below?**

I've written the following pattern to match all valid formats:

```
 p = re.compile(r"""
  (((?<=\ )|(?<=^))             #space or start of string
  ((\([0-9]{3}\))|[0-9]{3})     #Area code
  (((-|\ )?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})   #based on '-'
  |                             #or
  ((\.|\ )?[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{4})) #based on '.'
  (?=(\ |$)))                   #space or end of string
 """, re.X)
```

I want to modify the numbers so they adhere to the format:

```
\(\d{3}\)d{3}-\d{4}  #Ex: (123)456-7890
```

I tried using re.findall, and re.sub but had no luck.  I'm confused on how to deal with the circumstance of there being multiple matches on a line.

**EDIT:** Desired output:

```
["(123)456-7890 (321)654-0987",
"(111)111-1111",
"(222)222-2222",
"(333)333-3333",
"(444)444-4444",
"blah blah blah (555)555-5555",
"(666)666-6666 random text"]
```

Comment: Please provide all of the desired output for your example numbers.

Comment: @SangbokLee added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more simple solution that works for all of those cases, though is a little naïve (and doesn't care about matching brackets).

```
\(?(\d{3})\)?[ -.]?(\d{3})[ -.]?(\d{4})
```

Replace with:

```
(\1)\2-\3
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/3b2sVW/1)

**Explanation:**

Works by first checking for 3 digits, and optionally surrounding brackets on either side, with `\(?(\d{3})\)?`. Notice that the 3 digits are in a capturing group.

Next, it checks for an optional separator character, and then another 3 digits, also stored in a capturing group: `[ -.]?(\d{3})`.

And lastly, it does the previous step again - but with 4 digits instead of 3: `[ -.]?(\d{4})`

**Python:**

To use it in Python, you should just be able to iterate over each element in the list and do:

```
p.sub('(\\1)\\2-\\3', myString) # Note the double backslashes, or...
p.sub(r'(\1)\2-\3', myString)   # Raw strings work too
```

[Example Python code](http://codepad.org/VM6rQvuj)

---

**EDIT**

This solution is a bit more complex, and ensures that if there is a close bracket, there must be a start bracket.

```
(\()?((?(1)\d{3}(?=\))|\d{3}(?!\))))\)?[ -.]?(\d{3})[ -.]?(\d{4})
```

Replace with:

```
(\2)\3-\4
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/3b2sVW/3)