# How to split string into groups with some rules?

Tags: python

I want to make a function to split a string into multiple group. Every group will be divided by "-" and every element length is must 3, but if the last element length is 1, one character from the last two element will move into the last element. I don't know how to explain it in english, but I will try to provide the explanation by using my picture below :

[image]

I have write my own code like below :

```
    def groupNumber(x):
        for char in [' ','-']:
            if char in x:
                x=x.replace(char,"")
        t = [x[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]
        print('-'.join(map(str, t)))

    x='993141 -1 1323 14-232'
    groupNumber(x)
```

but it still shows wrong output.

Comment: you could use RegEx

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: try this it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755470/regex-sub-phone-number-format-multiple-times-on-same-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start by removing all non-digit characters using `re.sub`, and then split to chunks of three and check for the last string:

```
import re

def groupNumber(x):
    #   replace all '\D' (non-digit characters) with '' (i.e., remove them)
    x = re.sub(r'\D', '', x)
    #   extract chunks of three
    x = [x[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]
    #   if last string has length 1
    if len(x[-1]) == 1:
      #   move the last digit of the next-to-last string to the last string
      x[-2], x[-1] = x[-2][:-1], x[-2][-1] + x[-1]
    #   glue everything together with a `-` and return the result
    return '-'.join(x)

x='993141 -1 1323 14-232'
print(groupNumber(x))
```

Output:

```
993-141-113-231-42-32
```

Comment: Wow! This is what I am looking for! You are legend! Thank you!

Comment: Helpful, but it would be nice to show what the lines of code actually do. :-)